# Simple if condition with strings

Tags: c++, strcmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char name[100];
    cout<<"Enter: ";
    cin>>name;
    if(name == "hello"){
        cout<<"Yes it works!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why when I entered hello in the prompt i didnt got "Yes it works!" message?

Comment: Because `name` is not a string, it's a character array.

Comment: Use `std::string`! That code is vulnerable to buffer overflows. If you really are using C++, then you sohuld start using STL classes.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `strcmp` to test for equality.

`name` is an array, not a `std::string`, and `hello` is a string literal, i.e. a `const char*`. You're comparing pointers, not strings.

Comment: Keep in mind `strcmp` returns 0 if they're equal, so don't compare using `if (strcmp (name, "hello"))`

Comment: Yes. But now we should tell the OP that although in C++, `name` is not a string, it would be a string in C. And the comparison would still fail. How do we do that tactfully?

Comment: @chris all you need is en extra `;else`.

Comment: @MrLister, I was referring to the tendency to just use `if()`, not `if (... == 0)`. This is an easy source of logic errors.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char name[100];
    cout<<"Enter: ";
    cin>>name;

    if(strcmp(name, "hello") == 0) {
        cout << "Yes it works!"; 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't encourage people to use C-style methodology, especially in a situation with no error handling *(what happens if someone types in a 100-letter input?)*  Also, I was going to say that if one is going to use legacy C headers it should be `#include <cstring>` and not `#include <string.h>`...but in trying to find a reference on that I found it's not as cut-and-dry as I've been led to believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380805/difference-between-string-h-and-cstring

Comment: You're right. After reading Bo Perssons answer, I'd rather recommend his solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `std::string` instead of a char array, it will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    string name;
    cout<<"Enter: ";
    cin>>name;
    if(name == "hello"){
        cout<<"Yes it works!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are low-level strings ("C strings") which do not have the high-level behaviors you have probably come to expect from other languages.  When you type in a string literal (in "quotes") you are creating one of those types of strings:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling

In C++, one of the first things people do is pass that low-level string to the constructor of `std::string` to create an instance of a class that has more of the conveniences in interface that you would be used to.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Because C++ is layered over a very C-like foundation, it's valuable to understand how C-style strings work.  At the same time, a professional/idiomatic C++ program should not use functions like `strcmp`.  For an interesting study into the differences between C style programming and C++ style programming, check this out:

[Learning Standard C++ As A New Language (PDF)](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/new_learning.pdf) by Bjarne