# Why is namespace std not required for legacy C identifiers?

Tags: c++

This code is correct C++:

```
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
   std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
}
```

However, this compiles fine too (GCC 5.2):

```
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
   time_t t = time(nullptr);
}
```

More generally, it seems that legacy "C" data types and functions don't require namespace qualifying.

It seems to me that this is a dangerous behaviour, as both are accepted and the possibility of name collision is still there. I thought (erroneously ?) that the standard namespace `std` was there to protect me against this.

So my question is: why did the standardization committee allow such a behaviour in C++11 ? Am I wrong in my analysis ?

I understand the issues about legacy code, but I though the ".h" header files (`iostream.h`, ...) were there specifically to address this point.

**Edit**: the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606023) is not a duplicate, it asks about if one **should** or not use the `std::` version of legacy functions. What I want to know is the rationale behind this behaviour.

Comment: `iostream.h` is not in fact a standard C++ header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using C headers in C++, should we use functions from std:: or the global namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606023/when-using-c-headers-in-c-should-we-use-functions-from-std-or-the-global-na)

Comment: @Galik Could you elaborate ? ;-)

Comment: It turned out that on some systems, the C++ implementation just *have to* use the existing C functions. Perhaps because some of them *are* the system calls needed. So the C++11 standard just documented this "leak" between namespace std and the global namespace, as existing practice. It happened with C++98 as well, even though that standard didn't allow it.

Comment: @Bo-Persson Nice comment, consider adding as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++11, implementations are formally *allowed* to put C standard library names defined in `<cxxx>` headers in the global namespace. This doesn't mean that they are *required* to, so your second code sample may fail on a different platform.

So to say that `std` is not required for C identifiers is not entirely correct. It may not be required on some implementations, that is all.

Note that before C++11, many implementations did it anyway, although technically they weren't supposed to.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, just re-iterates what was asked. The question is "why" it is allowed, wha't the rationale.

Comment: @SergeyA Yeah, good point. I may delete this. I focused on the question title, which suggests the situation isn't properly understood by OP.