# What happened to std::assert

Tags: c++, c, namespaces, std, assert

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32606280/2642059) and it's multitude of duplicates indicate that I should be using `#include <c*>` for the C headers that I pull from in C++ code, and that I should be calling them with `std::*`.

I have been doing that but I notice an exception. `std::assert` doesn't seem to be defined, even when I correctly `#include <cassert>`.

What's going on here? Is this an implementation oversight, or an actual exception?

Comment: `assert` is a [macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)

Comment: `assert` is most likely implemented as a macro which cannot be used in namespace (because it doesn't produce language identifier like inline function does)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for the link, that's the only official piece of information thus far.

Comment: Perhaps you will find equal surprise in `stdout`, `errno`, `offsetof` and `va_start`?

Comment: I could never understand the value of this functionality. All funny things with invalidated variants usually happen in optimized code - and this is exactly when assert is suppressed. I am not following it.

Comment: @SergeyA Have you never tested your code ... ever?

Comment: @Barry, I am always testing my code. Spend more time testing it rather than writing, thanks for asking. However, I am not sure how it is relevant to run-time `assert`.

Comment: @SergeyA: I am with you on this one. Functionality that stops doing things when you are in production. So completely different behavior for production and debug code. If something is only going to go wrong while testing and not in production then you have some exceptional code. O hey wait we have something for exception situations.

Comment: @SergeyA: There's value in it to people who find your assertion *"All funny things with invalidated variants usually happen in optimized code"* to be false.

Comment: @SergeyA There is nothing preventing you using *assert* on optimized code.

Comment: @Galik I mean you'd need to disable the `NDEBUG` define... If your using Visual Studio's standard implementation that define is used to cull out all kinds of sub optimal behavior... so yeah, there kinda is something stopping you from using `assert` on optimized code.

Comment: What happened to reading [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To be honest I knew that `assert` was a macro, but it wasn't until getting responses on this bug that I realized that a macro was not scoped by namespace. I thought it was. So... nothing happened to reading the documentation, I read it as normal, it was just a lack of understanding of macros that inspired this question.

Comment: @JonathanMee Macros are handled by the C preprocessor (basically an automated copy/paste tool, at least when it comes to macros), and thus aren't there anymore by the time the code gets to the compiler.  Unless the macro directly expands to a function or class, there's nothing that could even conceivably go in a namespace; if it does expand to one of those, then what it expands into can go in a namespace, but [it itself will have been removed before we get there](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a20b8a55ec1633dd).

Comment: @JustinTime Right, I understand macros, I just didn't know that this *was* a macro. I wonder, are there any other macros in the library that I have as of yet failed to discover?

Comment: @JonathanMee Ah, okay.  I'm not sure, actually; I'm not aware of any other function-like macros in the standard library, but it's possible that some compilers might inadvertently let a few from their C standard libraries link through.

Comment: @JustinTime I'd be interested in seeing if there are any other macros that function similarly, if for no other reason just so I don't make this mistake again. I've asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44369648/2642059

Comment: A macro such as `assert` is converted into C++ source code by the preprocessor, not the compiler. This is a step which is done before the compiler. That's why it cannot be in a namespace as the others suggested.

Comment: @Galaxy Yeah, I actually never thought about standard stuff being implemented by macros when I asked this question. Interestingly there are several other standard macros as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44369648/2642059

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`assert` is a macro, not a function. Hence, it needs to be used with plain old `assert(condition)`.

Here's a supporting link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert.

Comment: Just thought a supporting link might be helpful here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: For reference: The C++17 standard lists this in chapter 20.5.1.2 paragraph 5 (`[headers]`): "Names which are defined as macros in C shall be defined as macros in the C ++ standard library [...]"

Answer (score 16):

`assert` is a macro, thus it isn't possible to restrict it to a namespace.