# Which C constructs appear in the std namespace?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, std, c-standard-library

The recommended way to include the C standard library header `<foo.h>` in C++ is to include the corresponding C++ header `<cfoo>`.

Based on my experience this puts *some* of of the corresponding C constructs into the `std` namespace, but others at global scope, and sometimes they appear in both places (i.e., in the `std` namespace and at global scope).

It depends on both the compiler (some like to include `size_t` only in `std` and not at global scope, others always have it at global scope), and on the construct (for example neither `assert` nor `error` ever seem to appear in the `std` namespace despite including `cassert` and `cerrno`).

What is required of the standard, and is there any simple rule to portably accessing C constructs in relation to the location in or out of the `std` namespace (something better than `using namespace std`)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32606023/149138) covers the same ground, but the answers there already reflect my understanding that `cfoo` puts everything in `std` - but doesn't answer the question of why things like `assert` and `errno` don't appear in `std` in that case, and how to know the full list of similar "exceptions".

Comment: @GManNickG - that question is a bit narrower (it's asking if stuff appears in the global namespace too - but my question is "how can I portably use any C construct"). The answer to that question seems to be "no" - but that leaves open the question of how to use any given construct. For example, "no" doens't mean that everything does appear in `std` since `assert` certainly doesn't (and probably anything else implemented as a macro). Also, the answers there kind of suck? The accepted one doesn't seem to answer the question (perhaps the quote was truncated).

Comment: in case of doubt, always add `std::`

Comment: @L.Kue - it doesn't work, consider `assert`.

Comment: @BeeOnRope `assert` is a macro, and not a function, hence no `std::` is used.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, The gist of the other Q&A is that including `<c___>` will guarantee names in `std::`. As for macros, you'll have to know what's a macro and what isn't. Many of them are all uppercase.

Comment: @L.Kue - sure, I know _why_ `assert` doens't appear in the standard namespace, but how am I supposed to apply that rule in general? `assert` may be documented to always be a macro, and macros may be documented to never appear in `std` (is that true?) - but I in general anything could be implemented as a macro in any particular implementation and I have no idea what those are. Consider for example `errno` which is not documented to be a macro, yet doesn't appear in `std` either on any compiler I tried.

Comment: @chris - is it guaranteed by the standard which things are macros and which aren't? The question is how to "know" and whether it is portable. I checked my local implementation and there are things which are implemented as macros, yet appear in the standard namespace (i.e., the macro resolves to something that appears in `std`). The examples I gave of `assert` and `errno` aren't uppercase.

Comment: Macros cannot have a namespace as they are not functions that are executed at runtime, they are used by the preprocessor during compile time. As chris said, you'll just have to know what's a macro and what isn't. That said, most IDE's provide you with suggestions for the correct syntax, as well as different syntax highlighting depending on whether something is a macro or a function.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, Macros can't have scope, so none can be in `std`. As for `errno`, see [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/errno#1), which says it's a macro. The standard distinguishes macros. Note that while not all macros are uppercase, very few aren't, so there are few special cases to learn.

Comment: @BeeOnRope I'm not certain if it's defined by the standard, but due to their nature, a macro will be a macro on any platform, and a function will be a function on any platform.

Comment: @L.Kue - it's totally up to the implementation which things are macros, so that is unsatisfactory.

Comment: @chris, sure macros can't have scope, but some macro `x` can certainly be "accessible" through `std`, since the macro substitution happens and then the `std::` qualifier is applied after and the result of the macro substitution may result in something appropriate to be prefixed with `std::`. Consider `#define vec vector` and then `std::vec` will "work".

Comment: @BeeOnRope, Sure, and I imagine an implementation could fit that under the as-if rule, but it doesn't affect your question in that case because you can't tell the difference; `std::<name>` would be portable. To my knowledge, `(std::<function name>)(...)` is supposed to work, so function macros wouldn't be permissible.

Comment: It’s *not* up to the implementation what is macro and what isn’t when using the `<c__>` header. Just always use `std::` and if it doesn’t work check the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) to see if it’s supposed to be that way and otherwise file a bug for your implementation.

Comment: Thanks @chris and L. Kue. I think it could be summarized as an answer: "In general everything will appear in the `std::` except things that are necessarily macros (and documented as such) which must be called unqualified. [insert part about determining what is a macro here]".

Comment: @BeeOnRope - some things specified in C standard headers are explicitly specified as being macros, and remains as macros in C++ forms of those headers.  `assert()` and `errno` are examples of that - they are still macros in the header `<cassert>`.

Answer (score 1):

Assert and errno are preprocessor macros and them being macros means they don't recognize namespaces and scopes. (preprocessor runs before compilation and does not respect any scope/namespace)

Everything else than macros in those `<cfoo>` headers should be placed in the std namespace.

Comment: So those two macros are the only exceptions - things that don't appear in `::std`?

Comment: No, everything that is a macro doesn't appear in `::std` - macros in general have no notion of namespaces. You can't actually put a macro inside a namespace. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I understand that macros have no concept of namespaces and are implemented by the pre-processor. That's not the question. The question is which C constructs don't appear in the `std` namespace? If the answer is 'all of those implemented as macros' then the question is whether that is defined by the standard and where I can look to see what is a macro.

Comment: Cppreference is a good resource, you can have a look at <cmath> to get the idea. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath