# c++ std:: types instead of corresponding c types

Tags: c++

For instance, consider the `<cstdint>` header. C++ standard [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdint#syn-2):

> The header defines all types and macros the same as the C standard library header `<stdint.h>`.

So is there a need to use say `std::int8_t` instead of the short C form `int8_t` somewhere?

Comment: I would say it's to make sure stuff in the `std` namespace can reference them without worrying too much about it getting resolved to some practical joke that someone declared in the global namespace.

Comment: Fairly similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606023/when-using-c-headers-in-c-should-we-use-functions-from-std-or-the-global-na

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is there a need to use say std::int8_t instead of the short C form int8_t somewhere?

Yes.  Per [[headers]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/headers#4) it is unspecified if the C names are defined in the global namespace or not.  Because of this you need `std::int8_t` to use `int8_t`.  It doesn't guarantee that `std::int8_t` exists, just that if it does exist, using `std::int8_t` is guaranteed to work.

You can just add `using std::int8_t;` so you don't have to type `std::int8_t` all over the place.

---

The relevant part of [headers]/4 is

> In the C++ standard library, however, **the declarations** (except for names which are defined as macros in C) **are within namespace scope of the namespace std**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

This means we know they are declared in `std::`.  The part

> It is unspecified whether these names (including any overloads added in [language.support] through [thread] and [depr]) are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations ([namespace.udecl]).

then allows the names to be in the global namespace, but does required it. This lets implementations do things like

`<cstdint>`:

```
namespace std
{
    #include <stdint.h>
}
```

or

`<cstdint>`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
namespace std
{
    using ::int8_t;
    using ::int16_t;
    //...
}
```

Bot accomplish the same thing (putting the names in `std::`) and are legal implementations but only the second one puts the names in the global scope.

Comment: The link you've provided says about the **order** of declaration - first in global namespace then in `std::` or vice-versa, not of existing only one of these. If I read it correctly. Futhermore I think the cite from my question should override type existance if your answer is right.

Comment: @älёxölüt I've updated the answer to elaborate more.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. In my expectation phrase *"The header defines all types and macros the same as the C standard library header <stdint.h>."* doesn't say that all names will be in `std::` only. I think *"defines all types"* means that all types will ne visible in global namespace too, same as I `#include <stdint.h>`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @älёxölüt You are incorrect.  Your quote says they are defined, and they are, but mine says they are scoped to the std namespace.

Comment: Do you know any compiler which use the latter `<cstdint>` implementation from your answer?

Comment: @älёxölüt [GCC does](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/c_global/cstdint).  Do note though that it could change at any time.

Comment: Oops ... sorry, I meant the first one, when only `std::` type are declared.

Comment: @älёxölüt I do not.  IIRC the big 3 all use the latter version.

Comment: @älёxölüt As far as I recall the C++03 standard required std::-only for the imported C-library but since the major players ignored this they changed the standard for C++11. The only compiler I know that implemented this requirement was the IAR C++ compiler but they switched  when moving to C++14.