# Difference between C++14 and C++17 using: `*p++ = *p`

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

While writing some code, I came across a problem where values I set were being set wrong. I eventually found the culprit line and while testing around found that it behaved differently on C++14 and C++17. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    uint8_t *p = new uint8_t[3];
    memset(p, 0x00, 1);
    p++;
    memset(p, 0xF0, 1);
    p++;
    memset(p, 0xFF, 1);
    p--;
    p--;

    // This line in particular
    *p++ = *p;

    *p++ = 0x0F;

    p--;
    p--;

    printf("Position 0 has value %u\n", *p);
    p++;
    printf("Position 1 has value %u\n", *p);
    p++;
    printf("Position 2 has value %u\n", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

On C++14 it prints:

```
Position 0 has value 240
Position 1 has value 15
Position 2 has value 255
```

And on C++17 it prints:

```
Position 0 has value 0
Position 1 has value 15
Position 2 has value 255
```

I'm curious why it acts differently on different C++ versions. It looks as though on C++14 the `*p` right side of the assignment is evaluated after the `++`. Did this change? And if the `++` has precedence, why does it not happen before the dereference on the left side of the assignment operator?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702220/what-made-i-i-1-legal-in-c17?rq=1)

Comment: Whether or not your code compiles is unspecified because it is unspecified whether `#include <stdio.h>` followed by `#include <cstring>` puts the name `memset` in the global scope.

Comment: @L.F. I don't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: @deW1 See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32606023

Comment: @deW1 They're saying that the OP included C++ `<cstring>` but wrote C `memset`, and that may fail to compile with some toolchains. The OP wanted `<string.h>` or `std::memset`. (And adding salt into the mix is that `<stdio.h>` may also transitively bring in `memset`!)

Comment: Yeah I just did a quick google how to include memset for testing and the first url on google threw me at <cstring> so I included that without much thought. I probably should of used `std::memset` then.

Comment: Technically you have the same problem with `uint8_t`

Comment: If `*p++ = *p` actually did what you seem to want it to do, why would you even code it instead of `p++` (or perhaps `*p++` if the value is needed)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In actual code I had bitwise operators after the `*p` to modify its value and store the modified version back in the same address (then increment the address), but omitted them while trying to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Reading from and writing to the variable (via the post-increment) used to have undefined behaviour, because the `=` did not introduce a sequence point. You could have received either behaviour (or none, or explosions) in C++14.

[Now, there is a sequencing order defined for this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47702440/560648) and your C++17 results are reliable.

Although it's still bad, unclear code that should not be written!

Comment: > *bad, unclear code that should not be written!*  Of course it's bad; the order is the wrong way, contrary to left-to-right; we shouldn't indulge in it.

Comment: @Kaz Actually, right-first evaluation is intuitive. Consider `CreateObject() = MayThrow()` - do you expect an object to be created if the RHS throws? Nope!

Comment: note that the example in the link differs from the original code (although the same standard quotes apply),  in `i = i++` (pre-C++17) the increment was unsequenced with the assignment, but in `*p++ = *p` the increment was unsequenced with the right operand value computation