# I just started c++ and made a calculator. What or how can I improve my code/ learn more?

Tags: c++, function, calculator

So I tried making a simple calculator that can input 2 floats and do basic operations (addition, subtraction, division, multiplication). This is the first time I'm writing a code without copying the entire thing from a tutorial. I did copy some bug fixes and other things but mostly I did it myself. I want criticism and I want to know what I could've done better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char start;
float num1, num2, result;
char op;

int menu(){
    cout<<"\nstart the program? \ny or n:\t";
    cin>>start;
    return 0;
}

int input_number(){
    cout<<"\nenter the first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    while (!cin){
        cout<<"Error. Number of elements must be numerical. Try again: " << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');  
        cin >> num1;
    }
    cout<<"\nenter the second number ";
    cin >> num2;
    while (!cin){
        cout<<"Error. Number of elements must be numerical. Try again: " << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');  
        cin >> num2;
    }
    return 0;
}

int input_op(){
    cout<<"\nenter which operation you want to execute (+,-,/,*): ";
    cin>>op;
    switch (op)
    {
    case '+': result= num1+num2; break;
    case '-': result= num1-num2; break;
    case '*': result= num1*num2; break;
    case '/': result= num1/num2; break;
    default: cout<<"wrong input";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    cout<<"-----Calculator X-----";
    menu();
    if (start=='y' || start== 'Y'){
        input_number();
        input_op();
        cout<<"the result is : "<<result<<'\n';
        menu();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"exiting program";
        return 0;}
}
```

Comment: There's a site dedicated to code review: [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- function don't need to return `0`, simply declare those as `void` return.

  - except `int main()`
- the `cin>>num; while(!cin){cin>>num;}` can be merged as `while(!(cin>>num))`
- ignore `256` char may not be enough

  - use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead
- for `ctype.h`, the corresponded c++ header is `cctype` ([relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32606023/5980430))

---

- you may actually return the result instead of store in global state.

  - `bool menu()`, `std::pair<int,int> input_number()`, `char input_op()`
- `input_number` may get single number instead of 2 (and be called twice)
- you don't check `op` is valid (unlike number inputs)

Comment: I'll try to use void functions, it was annoying to type return 0 every time.
I didn't know about (!cin), and I just copied it from another question posted here. same thing with the 256, I dont know what it does, I just copied the whole thing. 
I'll use the cctype header from now on.
ohh thats useful, I am a bit confused with the `std::pair<int,int> input_number();` how does it work?
How do I get two numbers if I call it twice, won't it store it in the same float?
I'll work on checking `op`

Comment: @Rayy21 function can return a value. so return a pair of `int` means return 2 value.

Comment: @Rayy21 The part of "call it twice" is meat to be when `input_number` return single `int`, so you call it twice to get 2 number. (instead of writing the same code twice with `num1` and `num2`)

Answer (score 0):

Want to add something to [@apple apple](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5980430/apple-apple) said. You don't need to define all the variables in the [global scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/)(`start`, `num1`, etc) in this specific case, just use them inside a functions or pass [them to a functions](https://www.infobrother.com/Tutorial/C++/C++_Call_by_ref_pointer) when needed. Hope it helped a little :^)