# Why is it that I have to use :: for some methods/declarations but not others?

Tags: c++, libraries, scope-resolution-operator

I am trying to wrap my head around the way C++ uses the scope resolution operator.

In this code snippet, I have a string pointer `gridPtr`, which needs the specification that it comes from the standard library. I sort of understand this, because the `<string>` header is in the standard library.  However, `printf()` doesn't need that same `std::` in front of it, despite being from the `<cstdio>` header, which is also in the standard library.

Why is this?

```cpp
#include "grid.h"

Grid::Grid(int a, int b){
    std::string* gridPtr; 
    gridPtr = new std::string(a,b);
}

Grid::Grid(int a, int b, std::string color){
    std::string* gridPtr;
    gridPtr = new std::string(a,b);
    printf("Your color is %s",color);
}
```

I also tried adding `std::` to `printf()` and there were no errors, adding further to my confusion.

Comment: [When using C headers in C++, should we use functions from std:: or the global namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32606023)

Comment: Technical point (which you can ignore if it's confusing): neither `std::string` nor `printf` is a keyword; they're identifiers defined in the library. identifiers like `if`, `else`, `return`, and `int` that mean something to the compiler are keywords.

Comment: You're right Pete! I edited my question to be more accurate. I have to keep in mind that keywords are not the same as methods or classes, but that something like 'class' is a keyword.