# Why is the last character of character array is getting excluded?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore();

    char arr[n+1];
    cin.getline(arr,n);
    cin.ignore();
    
    cout<<arr;

    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**
11
of the year

**Output:**
of the yea

I'm already providing n+1 for the null character. Then why is the last character getting excluded?

Comment: `char arr[n+1];` is not standard C++.

Comment: None of the duplicates answered the actual question.

Comment: `char arr[n+1];` -- As mentioned, this is not C++.  Either use `std::string`, or `std::vector<char> a(n + 1);`.

Comment: What's the reason for `char arr[n+1]` being non-standard C++? Some explanation will help others understand this.

Comment: @Aamir -- It is not standard because [variable length arrays are not part of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

Comment: @OP -- This array `char arr[n+1];` is not valid C++.  Thus the answer as to why your "array" behaves the way it does is totally up to the compiler vendor that happens to support the fake syntax.  As a matter of fact, those "arrays" did not work like regular arrays (compile errors) when given to an STL algorithm function for older versions of the g++ compiler.

Comment: @OP -- Also, if you are using a good C++ to learn from, there is no C++ book that shows declaring arrays like that.  So you must have picked up that syntax "by luck" when using a certain compiler, or you're learning from one of those websites that do not teach C++, but instead ask random puzzle questions.  This is why I wished `g++` compiler would turn off extensions by default, instead of leaving them on by default -- what winds up happening is a lot of new C++ programmers are getting fooled into thinking that those arrays are valid, when they are not.

Comment: Last, if you used Visual C++, that code [will fail to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/3eb7zEbvT), all for the reasons already outlined.

Comment: No good C++ book would advocate `cin.ignore();` either, it's another internet usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocated `n+1` characters for your array, but then you told `getline` that there were only `n` characters available. It should be like this:

```
int n;
cin>>n;
cin.ignore();

char arr[n+1];
cin.getline(arr,n+1);  // change here
cin.ignore();
cout<<arr;
```

Comment: Advocating the usage of non-standard C++ is one reason someone may have downvoted.

Comment: I'm not advocating anything. To help newbies learn I think it's important to concentrate on the thing they are asking about, not things they did not ask about. That VLAs are not valid C++ had already been mentioned so I didn't mention it again.

Comment: I've up-voted to make up for it. I think it's perfectly fine to only fix what is really broken and asked about. Although showing how to make it proper C++ as a second part to the answer would be benefitial.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Thanks. I do improve the OPs code sometimes, but in this case it the OPs code wouldn't make much sense even if improved, so I didn't bother. It struck me as some throwaway code written just to test getline.

Comment: My guess would be that the teacher knows C and getline is how you read a line since he doesn't know about "%m[^\n]s".

Answer (score 1):

Per cppreference.com:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

> Behaves as *UnformattedInputFunction*. After constructing and checking the sentry object, extracts characters from `*this` and stores them in successive locations of the array whose first element is pointed to by `s`, until any of the following occurs (tested in the order shown):
>
> 1. end of file condition occurs in the input sequence (in which case `setstate(eofbit)` is executed)
> 2. the next available character `c` is the delimiter, as determined by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`. The delimiter is extracted (unlike `basic_istream::get()`) and counted towards `gcount()`, but is not stored.
> 3. **`count-1` characters have been extracted (in which case `setstate(failbit)` is executed).**
>
> If the function extracts no characters (e.g. if `count < 1)`, `setstate(failbit)`is executed.
>
> **In any case, if `count > 0`, it then stores a null character CharT() into the next successive location of the array and updates `gcount()`.**

In your case, `n=11`. You are allocating `n+1` (12) chars, but telling `getline()` that only `n` (11) chars are available, so it reads only `n-1` (10) chars into the array and then terminates the array with `'\0'` in the 11th char. That is why you are missing the last character.

```
of the year
         ^
        10th char, stops here
```

You need to `+1` when calling `getline()`, to match your actual array size:

```
cin.getline(arr,n+1);
```

Comment: ok, but now code is asking for extra input

Comment: @ph0en1x Your input has 11 characters. By telling `getline()` the buffer is 12 chars in size, it reads in 11 chars from the input, and then terminates it with null. That is what you want. It doesn't ask for more input. However, as you can see from the description above, reading in that 11 chars will cause `failbit` to be set, so you will need to `clear()` that state before you can continue reading more input.

Answer (score 0):

john's answer should fix your issue. [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (your `char arr[n+1]`) are not part of the C++ standard, [for justified reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Yet I've taken a few hours of my time to go way out of question's scope and create the...

## Student's guide to C++ I/O

...and I/O in general, with an emphasis on the **I** part. Fear not, do it the C++ way! The following snippets should be compiled with a standard-conforming C++ compiler.

### C++ I/O & standard library

#### Textual input

This is the recommended way of reading [UTF-8 encoded strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) in C++, the most widespread text encoding. We will use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for storage, which is the de-facto way for holding UTF-8 encoded strings, and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for the reading itself.

```cpp
#include <iostream> // std::cin, std::cout, std::ws
#include <string>   // std::string, std::getline

int main() {
    int size;
    // std::ws ignores all whitespace in the stream,
    // until the first non-whitespace character.
    // it's prettier and handles cases a simple .ignore() does not.
    std::cin >> size >> std::ws;

    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    // This condition will most certainly be true (output will be 1).
    std::cout << (size == input.size()) << '\n';
}
```

`std::string` is dynamically allocated, or, as you may hear, [on the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap). This is a broad subject, so feel free to venture on your own, from this given starting point! How does this help us? We can store strings of sizes unknown ahead of time on the heap, because we can always reallocate a bigger buffer! `std::getline` allocates and reallocates as it reads the input until newline is reached, so you can read without knowing a `size` beforehand. Your `size` variable will most probably be equal with the size of the string under the assumption that this is a school exercise where the input length is provided as you're probably not taught of dynamic memory. For good reason, though - it's complex and would needlessly distract from the actual subject (algorithms, data structures etc.). Good to keep in mind: `std::string`s, unlike C-style strings, are not null terminated, but you can get a null-terminated C-style string from an `std::string` by calling the `.c_str()` method.

#### Binary data

What's [binary data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_data#In_computer_science)? Everything that's not text: images, videos, music, 2003 MS Word documents (the `.doc` ones, wait 'til you see [what `.docx` is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037905/what-is-the-structure-of-a-docx-and-doc-file)) and many others. It's customary to store binary as *raw bytes*, which is a fancy way to say numbers. `unsigned char` is the C/C++ type used to represent these raw bytes (C++17 introduces [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) for this purpose. To work with data from binary input we need to store it somewhere in memory - either on the stack, or on the heap. We could store the whole input at once, but binary files are considered too large for this (and, really, are - think about the size of a movie!), so we usually read it in *chunks* - that means, we read only a finite part of it at a time (say 256 characters, that's our *buffer*), and we keep reading until we reach the end of the input (usually called [*end-of-file* or, short, EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)). As a rule of thumb, when a buffer is small and static (doesn't need to be resized, as our string above), we can store it on the stack. If any of those conditions is not met, it goes on the heap. We should note that the notions of *small* and *large* are quite context dependent - compiler, OS, hardware, runtime environment (see [this thread on stack size limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program-on-mainstream-oses) and [embedded systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system)). The buffer size you'll choose is also task-specific, so there's no rule here, too. Let's see some code now!

```
#include <array>   // std::array
#include <fstream> // std::ifstream, std::ofstream

int main() {
    // We open this file in binary mode.
    // The default mode may modify the input.
    std::ifstream input{"some_image.jpg", std::ios::binary};
    // 256 is our buffer size, unsigned char is the array type.
    // This is the C++ way of `unsigned char buffer[256]`.
    std::array<unsigned char, 256> buffer;

    while (input.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size())) {
        // Buffer is filled, do something with it
    }

    // At this point, either EOF is reached or an error occurred.
    if (input.eof()) {
        // Less characters than the buffer's size have been read.
        // .gcount() returns the number of characters read by
        // the last operation.
        const std::streamsize chunk_size = input.gcount();
        // Do something with these characters, as in the loop.
        // Valid range to access in the buffer is [0, chunk_size).
        // chunk_size can be 0, too. In that case, there is no more data
        // to handle.
    } else {
        // Some other failure, handle error.
    }
}
```

This snippet is reading through a file using a small, stack-allocated buffer of 256 bytes. [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) makes usage convenient and safe with its methods - read the linked docs! If we want to use a large buffer (say, 16MB), we replace the `std::array` with an `std::vector`:

```cpp
std::vector buffer(1 << 24); // 1 << 24 gives 16MB in bytes
```

Rest is the same. You could also use `std::string` here, too, as `std::string` does not imply/force UTF-8 encoding of input. It's useful to have a convention that easily differentiates between binary and text data, in code.
Something to note is that reading in smaller chunks uses less space, but takes more time - taking bytes from a file involves [making OS system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_(system_call)) and moving disks or electrons, when reading from [a hard drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) or [an SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive), respectively. C++'s `fstream` objects already do buffering for you to speed up reads, which is usually a much-needed optimization. You'll know if this affects you.

Another thing to note is the `EOF` and error handling, using the [`.eof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) method. We have omitted error handling in the textual input retrieval, but here we are forced into doing it, if we don't want to lose data. When `EOF` is reached, usually less bytes than the buffer size have been read, so we need a way to know how much of the buffer was filled with data. This is what [`.gcount()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) tells us. Depending on the program you're making, you may deem the `EOF` error as "unexpected" if the buffer is partially filled (`.gcount()` returns a non-0 value) - for example, the data read is incomplete, according to the rules it was assumed to be created after, or in other words, the end of file was reached before the data was supposed to end. Other than that, `EOF` is a condition that all files are in after being fully read.

### C-style I/O

This may look closer to what's taught in school. As we've explained the general concepts above, this section will be richer in coding and explanations of code. We still use C++ as a language, so the C++ version of the C headers and the `std` namespace will be used - to have the code that follows work in a C compiler, replace the `<csomething>` headers with `<something.h>` and remove the `std::` namespace prefix from types and functions. Let's dive into it!

#### Textual input

The equivalent of a C++ stream (std::cin, std::fstream etc.) in C is the [`std::FILE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/FILE). `FILE`s are buffered by default, as are C++ streams. We'll use [`std::fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) for reading the size of the input, which is just `scanf` but it takes as parameter the stream you read from, and [`std::fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) for reading the text line.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>  // std::FILE, std::fscanf, std::fgets, stdin
#include <cstring> // std::strcspn

// discard_whitespace does what std::ws did above.
// It consumes all whitespace before a non-whitespace
// character from stream f.
void discard_whitespace(std::FILE* f) {
    char discard;
    // The leading space in the format string
    // tells fscanf to consume all whitespace.
    std::fscanf(f, " %c", &discard);
}

int main() {
    int size;
    // stdin is a macro, doesn't have a namespace,
    // hence no std:: prefix.
    std::fscanf(stdin, "%d", &size);
    // fscanf, like std::cin, doesn't consume whitespace
    discard_whitespace(stdin);

    // Your school exercise will probably have a size limit for the input.
    // We consider it to be 256.
    const int SIZE_UPPER_BOUND = 256;
    // We add some extra bytes so the maximum length input can be accomodated.    
    // 1 is added for the null terminator of C-style strings.
    // The other 2 is because `fgets` will also read the newline,
    // which can be \n or \r\n, depending on OS. See explanation after code.
    char input[SIZE_UPPER_BOUND + 3];

    // The actual read - sizeof gets the size of our input buffer,
    // we don't have to write it twice.
    std::fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    // fgets also reads the newline, unlike `std::getline` or
    // `std::cin.getline` - we have to remove it ourselves.
    input[std::strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = '\0';

    // This condition will be true, as in the C++ example.
    std::fprintf(stdin, "%d\n", std::strlen(input) == size);
}
```

Let's unpack that newline removal. [`std::strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcspn) finds the first position of any of the given characters in the input. We provide both `\r` and `\n`, to support UNIX (`\n`) and Windows (`\r\n`) newline terminators - yeah, they're different, [see Wikipedia, on "Newline"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). By adding the null terminator, '\0', we move the ending of the string where the newline was, basically "removing" the newline. If this is a school assignment, we can assume input is correct, so we could have used `size + 1` instead of `std::strcspn` to remove the newline:

```cpp
input[size + 1] = '\0';
```

This doesn't work when we don't know the input size or the input may be invalid.
As an optimization trick, observe that `std::strcspn` returns the line length, in this case. When you don't know the size, but you need it for later, you can save the result of `std::strcspn` in a variable before, and then use it instead of `std::strlen`:

```
// std::size_t is an unsigned integral type, used to represent
// array sizes and indexes in C/C++
const std::size_t input_size = std::strcspn(input, "\r\n");
input[input_size] = '\0';
```

You'll see some people use `0` or [`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL) for the terminator. I recommend against it - unlike the `\0` literal, that is of `char` type, the other two variants are implicitly casted to `char`. If you read the linked documentation, you'll realize `NULL` is even incorrect, according to the spec, as it's meant to be used in contexts that require pointers only.

An alternative method to `fgets` is `fscanf`, again. Thread carefully, though - while a simple `%s` may do it, it makes your code vulnerable to [buffer overflow exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). See [this StackOverflow thread on disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf), too. Let's see the (safe) code:

```cpp
std::fscanf(stdin, "%256[^\r\n]s", input);
```

That number limits the input size to our `SIZE_UPPER_BOUND`, and the `[^\r\n]` tells `fscanf` to read all characters up to `\r` or `\n`. With this method you can remove the `discard_whitespace` call, as `fscanf` with the `%s` verb consumes leading whitespace. A downside to `fscanf` is that you have to keep the size limit in the input string and the buffer size in sync - you have no way to specify the input size dynamically other than [building the format string dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459980/specifying-the-maximum-string-length-to-scanf-dynamically-in-c-like-s-in-pr), which is overkill for a school assignment). This is a problem in more sizable codebases, but for a one-file, one-time school assignment it's not a big deal, so you may prefer `fscanf` over `fgets`, as it's less work. `fscanf` doesn't read the newline in the buffer, too.

#### Binary data

The equivalent of C++'s `std::cin.read` in C world is [`std::fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread). Code will resemble its C++ counterpart:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    // The second parameter is the file access mode.
    // In this case, it is read (r) binary (b).
    std::FILE* f = std::fopen("some_image.jpg", "rb");
    unsigned char buffer[256];

    std::size_t chunk_size;
    while (chunk_size = std::fread(buffer, sizeof buffer[0], sizeof buffer, f)) {
        // chunk_size == sizeof buffer, do something with the buffer
    }

    if (std::feof(f)) {
        // chunk_size != sizeof buffer, do something with buffer
        // or handle as error
    } else {
        // an error occurred, handle it
    }

    // We need to close the file, unlike in C++, where it is closed automatically.
    std::fclose(f);
}
```

The arguments to `std::fread` are hairy: read the documentation. Everything else looks very similar to the C++ way, from the loop to the error handling. Why? Because it's literally the same thing - we're just using different (standard) libraries. Another similarity is that C I/O is also buffered by default, just like C++'s. What's different is the line at the end - the call to [`std::fclose`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fclose). We're not doing anything similar in the C++ code, right? No. Remember that C++ classes have [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) and [destructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor), functions that are automatically called at the beginning, respectively at the end of a variable's [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime). These two allow us to implement the [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii), which will do the resource management automatically (opening the file in the constructor, closing it in the destructor). RAII is used inside `std::string` and `std::vector` (and other [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) & others). In other words, the destructor of `std::ifstream` closes the file at the end of `main()`, just as we are doing here, manually.

### Hybrid approach (??)

Would you ever want to combine the two? So it seems. Let's talk drawbacks:

- The C++ I/O library, due to the way it's built, takes more care to use in a performant manner compared to C's ([`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) [function calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Efficiency) and extra function calls in general, especially when using [`<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) and [`>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) operators & [stream manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), as each of these is a function call, compared to a single plain function call/operation with the C library). See [this StackOverflow thread on i/ostream speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688763/why-is-istream-ostream-slow), too. The C++ library is also more verbose, especially in the case of outputting (ever heard of the ["chevrone hell"](http://ithare.com/cppcon2017-day-1-hope-to-get-something-better-than-chevrone-hell/)?)
- The C I/O library is easy to use improperly/unsafely, the terse, shorthand namings make code difficult to follow, and output cannot be extended to support custom types (this is a problem when using C-style I/O in C++). It also takes great care to handle dynamic buffers correctly, given that the only way of managing heap memory in C is [`malloc` and `free`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).
- Some schools may crucify you if any trace of `std::string` is left in sight (or so I've heard)
- Using C-style types (`char[N]` instead of `std::array<char, N>`, for example), is easier - no headers to include, as the types are builtin primitives and less to type. May be preferred in short, throwaway programs like algorithmic exercises at school.

With these in mind, we can take a look at how to conveniently combine the two when reading text and binary!

#### Textual input

We will take advantage of the terseness of C-style types and the ease of use of C++'s I/O library:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int size;
    std::cin >> size >> std::ws;

    const int SIZE_UPPER_BOUND = 256;
    char input[SIZE_UPPER_BOUND + 1];

    std::cin.getline(input, sizeof input);
    // Input done, solve the problem.
}
```

Teachers don't have to scratch their head at the presence of `std::string` and `std::getline` and all the standard library shenanigans you start using after diving in this rabbit hole. You, the programmer, don't have to clean up newline endings and memorize arcane format specifiers just to read a string and an int. Focus on code and solve problems without having to debug the input reading logic, ever - it just works!

#### Binary data

The convoluted [hierarchical tree of C++'s I/O library types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) scares you, the clean assembly output enjoyer, [just like Linus Torvalds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYvJPra7Ebk). You're still somehow afraid to manually manage memory, so you choose this solution:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // The second parameter is the file access mode.
    // In this case, it is read (r) binary (b).
    std::FILE* f = std::fopen("some_image.jpg", "rb");
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(1 << 24);

    std::size_t chunk_size;
    while (chunk_size = std::fread(buffer.data(), sizeof buffer[0], buffer.size(), f)) {
        // use the buffer
    }

    if (std::feof(f)) {
        // handle EOF
    } else {
        // handle error
    }

    std::fclose(f);
}
```

Weird choice, given that you still manage the file's lifetime manually. While this may not be the best example, using C++ RAII containers together with C libraries is not uncommon - memory safety is crucial.

### Trivia

- as usual, weigh your decision of [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Cool things you won't need:

- [speed up C++ I/O](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) using a single line at the beginning of the program ([but be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull))
- [disable C I/O buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380696/c-programming-write-to-file-without-buffer)
- [disable C++ I/O buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605233/how-to-disable-buffering-on-a-stream)

### Conclusion

I/O is the crowded junction of fundamental CS concepts, hardware & software inner workings and C++'s features and quirks. Take in what you can at a time & focus on what matters, and make sure you're building on sturdy fundamentals.